# Sequelize Polymorphic HasMany/HasOne through Join Table

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a Customer table, an Address table and a join table named CustomerAddress.
The customer needs a Shipping Address, a Billing Address, a Default Address, and all of the customer's addresses need to be accessible in a field `addresses`, this is because Address table is polymorphic.

I would like to do this without having a target key or foreign/target key in the Customer table or Address table, and rely on the CustomerAddress table to specify which address is which, this is what I have for the join table:

```
//CustomerAddress
    schema = {
      address_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique: 'customeraddress_address'
      },
      // Type of address eg. shipping, default, billing
      address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: 'customeraddress_address'
      },
      customer_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique: 'customeraddress_address',
        references: null
      }
    }
```

I'm not able to figure out how the associations need to be set up to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is actually through a belongsToMany association where you imply that it's a belongsTo. This way it uses the join table be default. The difference being that it returns an array instead of an object, which defeats the point. A compromise could be that when overriding the instanceMethod toJSON, you morph the array into an object, or make a custom setter/getter that does this when the association is fetched.